# Not able to extract groups of start and end HTML tags in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have this JavaScript array:

```
let a = [
    [0, "<p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of "],
    [1, "<strong>"],
    [0, "the"],
    [1, "</strong>"],
    [0, " printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type "],
    [-1,"and"],
    [1, "test"],
    [0, " scrambled it to make a type"],
    [1, "  added"],
    [0, "</p>"],
    [1, "<ul><li>test</li></ul>"]
];
```

I am trying to extract groups of the array based on the following condition:

Take a subarray of the above array as an example:

```
[1, "<strong>"],
[0, "the"],
[1, "</strong>"]
```

This sub-array is a group on the condition that `a[0] == 1` and `a[1]` is the beginning of a HTML tag. a[1] contains `<strong>` which is the beginning of any valid HTML tag, so I want to push the elements beginning at the start tag and till the end tag.

Like the following is one group:

```
let group = [
  {
    [1,"<strong>"],
    [0,"the"],
    [1,"</strong>"]
  },
  {
    [1,"<ul><li>test</li></ul>"]
  }
];
```

I want to extract the groups based on the following condition that:

1. The first index of an element is 1, that is `a[i][0] == 1` and
   `a[i][1]` is the beginning of a valid HTML tag
2. The first index of an element is 0, that is `a[i][0] == 0` and
   that it is preceded and succeeded by the the rules in Step 1 and 3.
3. The first index of an element is 1, that is `a[i][0] == 1` and
   `a[i][1]` is the end of a valid HTML tag.

These entire 3 rules will comprise a group or a JavaScript object.

There can be also one scenario like:

```
[1,"<ul><li>test</li></ul>"]
```

The array item contains the entire group `<ul><li>test</li></ul>`. That should also be included in the final result array.

## Edit

I have updated my approach

```js
let a = [
  [
    0,
    "<p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of "
  ],
  [
    1,
    "<strong>"
  ],
  [
    0,
    "the"
  ],
  [
    1,
    "</strong>"
  ],
  [
    0,
    " printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type "
  ],
  [-1,
    "and"
  ],
  [
    1,
    "test"
  ],
  [
    0,
    " scrambled it to make a type"
  ],
  [
    1,
    "  added"
  ],
  [
    0,
    "</p>"
  ],
  [
    1,
    "<ul><li>test</li></ul>"
  ]
];


checkAndRemoveGroups(a, 1);


function checkAndRemoveGroups(arr, group) {

  let htmlOpenRegex = /<([\w \d \s]+)([^<]+)([^<]+) *[^/?]>/g;
  let groupArray = new Array();
  let depth = 0;

  //Iterate the array to find out groups and push the items

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i][0] == group && arr[i][1].match(htmlOpenRegex)) {
      depth += 1;
      groupArray.push({
        Index: i,
        Value: arr[i],
        TagType: "Open"
      });
    }
  }

  console.log(groupArray);

}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do, but I'm quite sure you are going about it the wrong way.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I am trying to extract the subarray based on the 3 conditions I mentioned in the question

Comment: Your html regex is wrong: `let htmlRegex = /<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g` this works a little better.

Comment: @Axnyff yeah this Regex works, but I am not able to extract the group. Can you answer.

Comment: That's like trying to build a house out of toothpicks and expect it to be inhabitable.

Comment: @zer00ne edited the question

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array for opening and closing tags and check the length of it if some more tags are required to close the top tag.

```js
function getTags(string) {
    var regex = /<(\/?[^>]+)>/g,
        m,
        result = [];

    while ((m = regex.exec(string)) !== null) {
        // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
        if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
        }
        result.push(m[1])
    }
    return result;
}

var array = [[0, "<p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of "], [1, "<strong>"], [0, "the"], [1, "</strong>"], [0, " printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type "], [-1, "and"], [1, "test"], [0, " scrambled it to make a type"], [1, "  added"], [0, "</p>"], [1, "<ul><li>test</li></ul>"]],
    result = [],
    nested = [],
    tags,
    i = 0;

while (i < array.length) {
    if (array[i][0] === 1) {
        tags = getTags(array[i][1]);
        if (!tags.length) {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        result.push([]); // new group found
        while (i < array.length) {
            tags.forEach(function (t) {
                if (t.startsWith('/')) {
                    if (nested[nested.length - 1] === t.slice(1)) {
                        nested.length--;
                    }
                    return;
                }
                nested.push(t);
            });
            result[result.length - 1].push(array[i]);
            if (!nested.length) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
            tags = getTags(array[i][1]);
        }
    }
    i++;
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Scott... I think there must be a better way of doing what you want to do. I understand that you're trying to get things out of this array, but there's probably an entirely different approach to this problem where you don't have html nested inside of sub-arrays.

--
Edited - I misunderstood what you were looking for, so my original response didn't actually show you what was going wrong and I removed it. Looking some more at this.

Is this exactly what you want to receive? I don't see how you're ever going to get `[0,"the"]` if you're checking every element against the html regex. And every element is going to be in its own object, which doesn't seem to be what you want.

```
let group = [
  {
    [1,"<strong>"],
    [0,"the"],
    [1,"</strong>"]
  },
  {
    [1,"<ul><li>test</li></ul>"]
  }
];
```

Comment: I am just trying to extract groups matching those conditions.

Comment: It seems like you'd have to do something like:

Comment: Yeah that is what I want to extract.

Comment: ^^ Sent too soon,. Sorry, any answer I can think of to this would be super convoluted and time-consuming. Best I can do is suggest thinking about how you can keep track of whether an item is an opening tag so that you can somehow use that and alter your conditional to take it into account and include the next item in the group if it's NOT html.

Comment: You're still never going to get `[0, "the"]` because of the logic in your conditional:
`if (arr[i][0] == group`

`group` is `1` when you call `checkAndRemoveGroups(a, 1)`.